# What is the normalization Open-CV performs when using haar classifiers?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I am trying to implement haar cascade classifiers in FPGA using the xml files acquired from OpenCV. I am first writing a test program in python to determine if my logic is completely correct.

I understand the entire file format and the concept of integral images but the thing that is unclear and I can't find in documentation is how OpenCV goes from the large rect values to the feature threshold of, for example 0.5

normalizing by dividing the sum with the sum of the entire matrix appears to be way too small and keeps failing at the same stage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You understand the integral image, but do you understand the haar-features and the decision trees? It is some time ago and I never implemented it, but afair I was able zo follow all the logical steps in the end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.